# pfSense and USB ethernet

Tags: networking, pfsense

I'm looking to build a pfSense box at home. It seems most ideal to locate a machine with dual ethernet, and designate them WAN and LAN. But I was wondering if it would make sense to use a machine I already own with one ethernet port to operate LAN, and plug in a USB ethernet port to operate WAN.

What would be the drawbacks of using a USB ethernet adapter in a firewall vs built-in ethernet? I would expect some sort of latency hit as traffic gets translated ethernet -> usb -> ethernet, but is this something to be concerned about in practice?

Comment: Have you already considered adding Ethernet ports via PCIe instead?

Comment: The machine I had in mind is an HP EliteDesk Mini G2, which has limited expansion options. There is an M.2, and I guess in theory I could get adapt it for a PCIe NIC, but I feel that would be a lot of trouble.

Comment: The latency hit will almost certainly be miniscule (< 1ms), especially compared to the small latency introduced by the firewall itself. And unless your WAN is very fast, and you need to get every bit of speed possible out of it, then I doubt that even a USB 2 Ethernet  adapter will have trouble keeping up with your actual traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I made a device such like this. I had a HP notebook and I wanted to turn to a router. There was a built-in NIC so I bought an USB NIC. pfsense was on 2.5.x - I cannot recall - but it worked perfectly.

This is not an enterprise solution but would work on a LAN so I have never cared about the bottlenecks but your question can be valid though.

If you would like to understand the connection between USB and PCI bus there is a good topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723481/relation-between-usb-and-pci

I would say there is some latency handling packages through an USB NIC but considering the solution itself it is not something that you need to care about.